# Uncommitted transaction asking every time in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions, ssms

I am facing issues like whenever I open SQL windows and run any SQL transaction (insert, update or delete or any modification in procedure), it asks about uncommitted transaction.

How to fix this permanently?

Comment: Please give more information

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL windows" ? SQL Server Management Studio ??

Comment: there are uncommitted transaction . do you wish to commit this transactioins before closing the windows

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you probably have [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on.

This will open a new transaction implicitly when it encounters statements such as insert, update or delete and no transaction is open and will require an explicit `commit` or `rollback`.

> Implicit transactions may unexpectedly be ON due to ANSI defaults. For details see SET ANSI_DEFAULTS (Transact-SQL).
>   IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON is not popular. In most cases where IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON, it is because the choice of SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON has been made.

You need to go into the connection properties and ensure you have not enabled implicit transactions either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: i just uncheck the Implicit_transactions off in tools-option-sql server-ANSI-set implicit_transactions off

Comment: @wasim - good to hear. Don't forget to tick the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` you also need to either `COMMIT TRANSACTION` if it has done all the work you want correctly or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` if there has been issues and you want to return to the state before the start of the transaction.

Read up on transactions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)